# jquery ui sortable cannot drop cell into newly visible div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[Simplest to see in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ayr2Loz/)

```
Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code, therefore I am copying the js here:

$('.row').sortable({
    placeholder: 'cell placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        items: '.cell',
        connectWith: '.row',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        distance: 0.5,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        start: function() {
            $('.row').css('min-height','30px');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $('.row').css('min-height','');
        }
});
```

the problem is, if I have two or more rows and one of them is being made visible after the cell is clicked on to being the drag, then the empty row cannot be dropped into unless the call is first hovered over another non-empty possible destination.

To see this in practice, click on the cell "iop" and try and drag it down into the thrid row. It doesn't work. BUT, if you click on the cell "iop", drag it up into the first row and then - without releasing it - back down into the third row, it does!

I presume that this has something to do with when sortable builds its internal list of possible targets. But, is there any way to make the empty row visible only once the dragging has started, and still have it targetable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing sortable seems to do it:

```
$('.row').sortable('refresh');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kfdmn9nm/

Comment: This only works for the last row, it doesn't make the middle row invisible. And, doesn't an invisible element still affect the flow?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it creates a new problem. Try this: after you min-width call, add $('.row').sortable('refresh');